# Aggregate on two collections and get highest value

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I would like to have the number of views of a post that has been viewed the most. Below is a small example.

**Users:**

```
{
   username: "John"
},
{
   username: "Doe"
}
```

**Messages:**

```
{
   title: "Lorem Ipsum!",
   views: 400,
   author: "John"
},
{
   title: "Lorem Ipsum!",
   views: 200,
   author: "John"
},
{
   title: "Lorem Ipsum!",
   views: 100,
   author: "John"
},
{
   title: "Lorem Ipsum!",
   views: 403,
   author: "Doe"
},
{
   title: "Lorem Ipsum!",
   views: 299,
   author: "Doe"
},
```

I want to have a property for each user on the object that contains the highest number of views of a message. Like this:

```
{
   username: "John"
   highest_view: 400
},
{
   username: "Doe"
   highest_view: 403
}
```

I could solve this in code by looping through and querying each object, but that doesn't seem like the most convenient way.

Comment: You can probably use the groupBy function describe in answer of this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects by Kmylo darkstar. Using a group by on username property and then loop + reduce to get the higher for each username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query1

- aggregate on users, lookup with Messages
- `$max` to keep the max value of the array from the path `$highest_views.views`

*`$max` is accumulator but also works on arrays

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0mooPPdb8Tk)

```js
users.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
    {"from": "Messages",
      "localField": "username",
      "foreignField": "author",
      "as": "highest_views"}},
 {"$set": {"highest_views": {"$max": "$highest_views.views"}}}])
```

Query2

- this is better, but a bit more complicated
- if you have big collections i think go for this one
- `$lookup` with pipeline, group to get the max views
- fix structure to get the expected output

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6Whc516JLxc)

```js
users.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
    {"from": "messages",
      "let": {"username": "$username"},
      "pipeline": 
      [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$$username", "$author"]}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": null, "highest_views": {"$max": "$views"}}}],
      "as": "highest_views"}},
  {"$set": 
    {"highest_views": 
      {"$arrayElemAt": ["$highest_views.highest_views", 0]}}}])
```

Comment: Awesome answer. You answers are of quality without compromising on response time. Appreciate your dedication and knowledge!

Comment: thank you hhharsha, this answer was simple, i just tried to give both ways i could think of.